# Why does Spark application fail with "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ...StringDeserializer"?

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-kafka-streams

I am developing a Spark application that listens to a Kafka stream using Spark and Java.

I use kafka_2.10-0.10.2.1.

I have set various parameters for Kafka properties: `bootstrap.servers`, `key.deserializer`, `value.deserializer`, etc.

My application compiles fine, but when I submit it, it fails with the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/StringDeserializer
```

I do use `StringDeserializer` for `key.deserializer` and `value.deserializer` so it's indeed related to how I wrote my application.

Various maven dependencies used in `pom.xml`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have tried updating the version of spark streaming/kafka. I could not find much anywhere.

Comment: How do you `spark-submit` your Spark app?

Comment: In this way:  spark-submit --verbose --master local[3] --class ClassName target/uber.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> spark-streaming_**2.10**

This is dependent upon Scala 2.10

Your other dependencies are using Scala 2.11

[Upgrading the version](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#basic-concepts) is the correct solution for the current error.

And make sure that within streaming-kafka-**0-10**, this matches the version of Kafka you're running

> Application is compiling fine but when I am trying to submit the spark job, its showing error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

[By default, maven does not include dependency jars when it builds a target](https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/troubleshooting/missing_dependencies_in_jar_files.html)

Comment: I tried changing all the versions to 2.10 as well as 2.11 (keeping all other dependencies either 2.10 or 2.11) but still error persists. Can there be any other issue also?

Comment: If the code compiles, but fails at runtime, the classpath is wrong, and you're not building an uber jar when you submit the job

Answer (score 3):

As you mentioned in [the comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44748924/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-kafka-comm#comment76480029_44748993):

> Turned out issue was with uber jar not building correctly.

That's exactly the issue. It does relate to how you assemble your Spark application and I'm worried to think you may have chosen a uber jar way. It's in my opinion a waste of your time at assemble and spark-submit time.

I'd personally prefer using `--packages` command-line option that takes care of pulling down all the necessary dependencies if needed.

```
$ ./bin/spark-submit --help
...
  --packages                  Comma-separated list of maven coordinates of jars to include
                              on the driver and executor classpaths. Will search the local
                              maven repo, then maven central and any additional remote
                              repositories given by --repositories. The format for the
                              coordinates should be groupId:artifactId:version.
...
```

That makes your life as a Spark developer easier and it's no longer you to wait till maven/sbt downloads the dependencies and assemble them together. It's done at `spark-submit` time (and perhaps it's someone else's job, too! :))

You should `spark-submit` as follows:

```
spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.1.1 ...
```

The reason for this extra requirement is that `spark-streaming-kafka-0-10` module is not included by default in Spark's CLASSPATH (as it's considered unnecessary most of the time). By doing the above `--packages` command line you trigger loading the module (with its transitive dependencies).

You should not bundle the module in your Spark application's uber jar.

Answer (score 1):

> Turned out issue was with uber jar not building correctly.
> In case you would like to assemble the application and package an uber jar.

Create an assembly file in `src/assembly/assembly.xml`

```xml
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.1.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.1.0.xsd">
    <id>bin</id>
    <formats>
        <format>jar</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <unpack>true</unpack>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

And add the `maven-assembly-plugin` to the `pom.xml`

```xml
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>src/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

If you would like to add a dependency to the uber jar, just add provided scope to it.
In your case, it will be like this:

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>0.10.2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

```sh
$spark-submit --class Main application-bin.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use shade plugin to generate fat jars if that is prefered to you wrt. what Jacek proposed via --packages approach.

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

You can also use maven-dependency plugin to fetch some of the dependencies and put it in your assembly in lib directory and latter supply it to spark.

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy</id>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <artifactItems>
                        <artifactItem>
                            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
                            <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
                            <type>jar</type>
                            <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/log4j-v2-jars</outputDirectory>
                            <destFileName>log4j-v2-core.jar</destFileName>
                        </artifactItem>
                        <artifactItem>
                            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
                            <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
                            <type>jar</type>
                            <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/log4j-v2-jars</outputDirectory>
                            <destFileName>log4j-v2-api.jar</destFileName>
                        </artifactItem>
                        <artifactItem>
                            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                            <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
                            <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
                            <type>jar</type>
                            <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/log4j-v2-jars</outputDirectory>
                            <destFileName>log4j-v2-1.2-api.jar</destFileName>
                        </artifactItem>
                        <artifactItem>
                            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
                            <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
                            <type>jar</type>
                            <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/log4j-v2-jars</outputDirectory>
                            <destFileName>log4j-v2-slf4j-impl.jar</destFileName>
                        </artifactItem>
                    </artifactItems>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/wars</outputDirectory>
                    <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                    <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

The reason why I am proposing this is because maybe in your case (as it was the case with my work) your cluster is behind a very strict firewall and spark is not allowed to talk to nexus for resolving packages at submit step. In that case you really do need to handle this at artefact preparation and either of these might help you.

In my example with maven-dependency I fetch log4jv2 to pass it to spark 2.3 in order to have log4j-v2 log outputs (you can place your dependencies instead).