# GCP dataproc - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/ByteArraySerializer

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, pyspark, apache-kafka, google-cloud-dataproc

i'm trying to run a StructuredStreaming job on GCP DataProc, which reads from Kafka nd prints out the values. The code is giving error -> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/ByteArraySerializer

Here is the code:

```
import sys, datetime, time, os
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, rank, dense_rank, to_date, to_timestamp, format_number, row_number, lead, lag,monotonically_increasing_id
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, Window
from confluent_kafka import Producer
from google.cloud import storage

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('StructuredStreaming_VersaSase').getOrCreate()

spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

kafkaBrokers='34.75.148.41:9094'
topic = "versa-sase"
# bootstrap.servers=my-cluster-lb-ssl-cert-kafka-bootstrap:9093
security_protocol="SSL"


client = storage.Client()
print(" client ", client)

bucket = client.get_bucket('ssl-certs-karan')
print(" bucket ", bucket)

allblobs = bucket.list_blobs()
print(" allblobs -> ", allblobs)

for b in allblobs:
    print(" b -> ", b)

blob_ssl_truststore_location = bucket.get_blob('ca.p12')
print(" blob_ssl_truststore_location.name ", blob_ssl_truststore_location.name)
blob_ssl_truststore_location.download_to_filename(blob_ssl_truststore_location.name)

ssl_truststore_location=blob_ssl_truststore_location.name
print(" type - blob_ssl_truststore_location ", type(blob_ssl_truststore_location))
ssl_truststore_password="NAvqbh5c9fB4"

blob_ssl_keystore_location = bucket.get_blob('dataproc-versa-sase.p12')
print(" blob_ssl_keystore_location.name ", blob_ssl_keystore_location.name)
blob_ssl_keystore_location.download_to_filename(blob_ssl_keystore_location.name)
ssl_keystore_location=blob_ssl_keystore_location.name
ssl_keystore_password="jBGsWrBv7258"
consumerGroupId = "versa-sase-grp"
checkpoint = "gs://ss-checkpoint/"

print(" SPARK.SPARKCONTEXT -> ", spark.sparkContext)



df = spark.read.format('kafka')\
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers",kafkaBrokers)\
    .option("kafka.security.protocol","SSL") \
    .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.location",ssl_truststore_location) \
    .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.password",ssl_truststore_password) \
    .option("kafka.ssl.keystore.location", ssl_keystore_location)\
    .option("kafka.ssl.keystore.password", ssl_keystore_password)\
    .option("subscribe", topic) \
    .option("kafka.group.id", consumerGroupId)\
    .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
    .load()
#


query = df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)") \
    .write \
    .format("console") \
    .option("numRows",100)\
    .option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint) \
    .option("outputMode", "complete")\
    .save("output")

# query.awaitTermination()
```

## Command to launch the job on Dataproc cluster :

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark \
StructuredStreaming_Kafka_GCP-Batch-feb1.py --cluster=dataproc-ss-poc 
--jars=gs://spark-jars-karan/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.1.2.jar     
--region=us-central1
```

Error :

```
 SPARK.SPARKCONTEXT ->  <SparkContext master=yarn appName=StructuredStreaming_VersaSase>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/b87ff69307344e2db5b43f4a73c377cf/StructuredStreaming_Kafka_GCP-Batch-feb1.py", line 49, in <module>
    df = spark.read.format('kafka')\
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 210, in load
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1304, in __call__
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 111, in deco
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o69.load.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/ByteArraySerializer
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider$.<init>(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:556)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider$.<clinit>(KafkaSourceProvider.scala)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider.org$apache$spark$sql$kafka010$KafkaSourceProvider$$validateBatchOptions(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:336)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider.createRelation(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:355)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:325)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$3(DataFrameReader.scala:307)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:307)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:225)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
```

I've checked the Spark version on the Dataproc cluster, and spark version - 3.1.2,and scala version - 2.12 .. so the version of the spark-sql jar being passed seems to be correct.
Are there any other jars to be passed ?

What needs to be done to fix/debug this issue ?

tia !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spark fails with NoClassDefFoundError for org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54569033/spark-fails-with-noclassdeffounderror-for-org-apache-kafka-common-serialization)

Comment: @MartinZeitler - from what i understand ..  when i do -> spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.1.2, it will pull all the dependant jars and that work fine however .. what do i need to do on Dataproc to make it work ? Do i need to pass individual jars in which case - i'll need to figure out the jars to be added .. or can i pass package name ?

Comment: What error do you get when you use `--packages` with a maven target instead of `--jars` with a file? Otherwise, you need to at least get `kafka-clients.jar` and all other possible dependencies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i was able to resolve this issue, by passing the package as below
i.e. --properties spark.jars.packages=org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.1.2
Pls note : i also added the individual jars initially to resolve the issue, however that clearly is not the right way

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark /Users/karanalang/Documents/Technology/gcp/DataProc/StructuredStreaming_Kafka_GCP-Batch-feb2.py  --cluster dataproc-ss-poc  --properties spark.jars.packages=org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.1.2 --region us-central1
```

Answer (score 4):

The missing class `org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/ByteArraySerializer` is in the `kafka-clients` package [1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients/0.10.2.2) which is a dependency of the `spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12` package [2](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12/3.1.2).

You can use either `--packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.2.1` which automatically pulls the transitive dependencies, or `--jars=gs://my-bucket/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.1.2.jar,gs://my-bucket/kafka-clients-0.10.2.2.jar` to add all the dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at the official deployment guideline here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#deploying

Extracting the important part:

```
./bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.2.1 ...
```

All in all please use "--packages" instead of "--jar" because it takes care transitive dependencies.

Comment: OP is using dataproc, not `spark-submit`

Comment: OK, the main message is that packages handle transitive deps but jars not.

Comment: Sure. My point was that maybe `--packages` is not a valid argument to `dataproc jobs submit` command