# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'selectExpr'

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-kafka

```
import logging
import findspark
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType



def create_keyspace(session):
    session.execute("""
        CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS spark_streams
        WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '1'};
    """)

    print("Keyspace created successfully!")


def create_table(session):
    session.execute("""
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS spark_streams.created_users (
        id UUID PRIMARY KEY,
        first_name TEXT,
        last_name TEXT,
        gender TEXT,
        address TEXT,
        post_code TEXT,
        email TEXT,
        username TEXT,
        registered_date TEXT,
        phone TEXT,
        picture TEXT);
    """)

    print("Table created successfully!")


def insert_data(session, **kwargs):
    print("inserting data...")

    user_id = kwargs.get('id')
    first_name = kwargs.get('first_name')
    last_name = kwargs.get('last_name')
    gender = kwargs.get('gender')
    address = kwargs.get('address')
    postcode = kwargs.get('post_code')
    email = kwargs.get('email')
    username = kwargs.get('username')
    dob = kwargs.get('dob')
    registered_date = kwargs.get('registered_date')
    phone = kwargs.get('phone')
    picture = kwargs.get('picture')

    try:
        session.execute("""
            INSERT INTO spark_streams.created_users(id, first_name, last_name, gender, address, 
                post_code, email, username, dob, registered_date, phone, picture)
                VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
        """, (user_id, first_name, last_name, gender, address,
              postcode, email, username, dob, registered_date, phone, picture))
        logging.info(f"Data inserted for {first_name} {last_name}")

    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f'could not insert data due to {e}')


def create_spark_connection():
    s_conn = None

    try:
        s_conn = SparkSession.builder \
            .appName('SparkDataStreaming') \
            .config('spark.jars.packages', "com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.13:3.4.1,"
                                           "org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.13:3.4.1") \
            .config('spark.cassandra.connection.host', 'localhost') \
            .getOrCreate()

        s_conn.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
        logging.info("Spark connection created successfully!")
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Couldn't create the spark session due to exception {e}")

    return s_conn


def connect_to_kafka(spark_conn):
    spark_df = None
    try:
        spark_df = spark_conn.readStream \
            .format('kafka') \
            .option('kafka.bootstrap.servers', 'localhost:9092') \
            .option('subscribe', 'users_created') \
            .option('startingOffsets', 'earliest') \
            .load()
        logging.info("kafka dataframe created successfully")
    except Exception as e:
        logging.warning(f"kafka dataframe could not be created because: {e}")

    return spark_df


def create_cassandra_connection():
    try:
        # connecting to the cassandra cluster
        cluster = Cluster(['localhost:9042'])

        cas_session = cluster.connect()

        return cas_session
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Could not create cassandra connection due to {e}")
        return None


def create_selection_df_from_kafka(spark_df):
    schema = StructType([
        StructField("id", StringType(), False),
        StructField("first_name", StringType(), False),
        StructField("last_name", StringType(), False),
        StructField("gender", StringType(), False),
        StructField("address", StringType(), False),
        StructField("post_code", StringType(), False),
        StructField("email", StringType(), False),
        StructField("username", StringType(), False),
        StructField("registered_date", StringType(), False),
        StructField("phone", StringType(), False),
        StructField("picture", StringType(), False)
    ])

    sel = spark_df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)") \
        .select(from_json(col('value'), schema).alias('data')).select("data.*")
    print(sel)

    return sel


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # create spark connection
    spark_conn = create_spark_connection()

    if spark_conn is not None:
        # connect to kafka with spark connection
        spark_df = connect_to_kafka(spark_conn)
        selection_df = create_selection_df_from_kafka(spark_df)
        session = create_cassandra_connection()

        if session is not None:
            create_keyspace(session)
            create_table(session)

            logging.info("Streaming is being started...")

            streaming_query = (selection_df.writeStream.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
                               .option('checkpointLocation', '/tmp/checkpoint')
                               .option('keyspace', 'spark_streams')
                               .option('table', 'created_users')
                               .start())

            streaming_query.awaitTermination()
```

I have a problem while executing  " spark-submit --master spark://localhost:7077 .\spark_stream.py"

it does creare a worker in spark ui but i does not fetch the data coming from kafka

I'm using airflow that triggers a DAG from an API to stream data then the data  goes into kafka then proccessed in spark then saved into cassandra

am facing an issue with spark and kafka as it is not apprarently communicating properly
taking in consideration that i testted each and every component separatly and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'selectExpr'

This means that whatever `x.selectExpr` is, `x` is [`None`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#None).

In your code, inside the function `create_selection_df_from_kafka`, you call

```py
spark_df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
```

Therefore, the `spark_df` *argument* is `None`.

In your code, on the global scope inside the `if __name__ == '__main__':` check, you call

```py
selection_df = create_selection_df_from_kafka(spark_df)
```

Therefore, the `spark_df` *variable* is `None`.

Previous in the same scope, you call

```py
spark_df = connect_to_kafka(spark_conn)
```

Therefore, `connect_to_kafka(spark_conn)` is returning `None`.

Inside the `connect_to_kafka` function, you call

```py
return spark_df
```

However, there is a situation where `spark_df` is not assigned, which is inside the `except`-block of the `try-except` clause. So you must handle it.

Comment: honestly this was not helpful
thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are learning the same course as me because I also encountered this error. I have handled the `try-catch` clause in the `create_selection_df_from_kafka` function and it returns this error:

```
WARNING:root:kafka dataframe could not be created because: An error occurred while calling o36.load.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/$less$colon$less
```

The root cause of this issue is missing some jar files and it cannot compiled. I have done some research and figured out 3 missing packages:

- `spark-cassandra-connector`
- `spark-sql-kafka`
- `kafka-clients`

What you can do is:

1. Double-check the [Kafka version](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/versions-interoperability.html#cp-and-apache-ak-compatibility), Spark, Cassandra, and Scala versions from the `docker-compose.yml` file.
2. Find the right version of the jars package in the config of Spark Session on Maven and download it.

For example, I use `Spark 3.5.1`, `Cassandra 5.0`, `Confluent Platform 7.6.0` which support `Kafka 3.6.x` so I download the jar files of these packages:

- [`spark-cassandra-connector_2.12:3.5.0`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.spark/spark-cassandra-connector_2.12/3.5.0)
- [`spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.5.1`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12/3.5.1)
- [`kafka-clients:3.7.0`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients/3.7.0)

3. Go to `venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyspark/jars` path and add 3 jar files to the jars folder.
4. Run your `spark-submit` again and it's good to go.

References:

- [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70951195/gcp-dataproc-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-kafka-common-serializa/71059689#71059689) for the `kafka-clients` package.
- [The issue](https://github.com/airscholar/e2e-data-engineering/issues/4) on GitHub and [my answer](https://github.com/airscholar/e2e-data-engineering/issues/4#issuecomment-1980654717) for that issue.